# Get single value from JSON object with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

following the jquery script coding

[image]
[image]

case here I want to retrieve data based on "Sub Total" but I am confused for the coding

Comment: add the actual code and array in the OP not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Use array.find

```
var nomor = data.find(t=t.nomor ==='Sub Total');
```